# Unity doesn't work on Nvidia ION

Tags: unity, nvidia, asus

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Asus 1201N and Unity refuses to work after installing the nvidia binary drivers. It works fine on the default, but those are no where good enough when it comes to playing games. This is the output of unity_support_test:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: GLX is not available on the system
```

I can't find any ways to fix this. The setup is as pure as possible with absolutely no additional software, so it can't be something I installed.

EDIT: Oh, and with the open nouveau driver, everything works fine. I'd like to run the nvidia driver though.

Comment: It appears that 202677 is exactly my problem. If the solution works, I'll add another comment here saying so.

Comment: Yay, it works! If anyone were to mark this as duplicate it'd be nice.